# Change margins on ImageView programmatically - Android

Tags: android, imageview, android-alertdialog, margins

I'm creating AlertDialog with two ImageViews lika buttons, but I don't know how to set the right margin of first ImageView, because I want to have space between them. My code:

```
        Context context = Main.this;

        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

        // Layoutot
        LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(context);
        layout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,   // width
                                                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)); // height

        // Image Edit
        ImageView Edit = new ImageView(context);
        Edit.setImageResource(R.drawable.edit);
        Edit.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button);
        Edit.setPadding(5, 20, 5, 20);
        Edit.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, // width
                                                          LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, // height
                                                          1f));                      // weight

        // Image Delete
        ImageView Delete = new ImageView(context);
        Delete.setImageResource(R.drawable.delete);
        Delete.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button);
        Delete.setPadding(5, 20, 5, 20);
        Delete.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, // width
                                                          LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,   // height
                                                          1f));                        // weight

        layout.addView(Edit);
        layout.addView(Delete);
        alert.setView(layout);

        alert.show();
```

I've tried something like this, but I it show only first (Edit) button

```
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams margins = new
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams(Edit.getLayoutParams());
        margins.setMargins(0, 0, 15, 0);
        Edit.setLayoutParams(margins);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `rightMargin` for this...

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams margins = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(Edit.getLayoutParams());
margins.rightMargin = 15;
Edit.setLayoutParams(margins);
```